# Heroku Python binary library dependency

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku, apt

I need to run code on my Heroku Django project that requires the Python package [`dm.xmlsec.binding`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dm.xmlsec.binding/1.3.1). This in turn, depends on having the binary `apt` package `libxmlsec1` installed, usually via `apt-get install`.

That is how I have things running locally on an Ubuntu vagrant box.

#### Deploying to Heroku: Approach

I have two "build packs" in my application. Having multiple buildpacks is enabled by using [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi).

Since my application is a Python one, my `.buildpacks` contents are therefore:

```
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
```

The first buildpack, which refers to [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt), requires an `Aptfile` to specify `apt` packages; in our case the contents of this file are:

```
python-setuptools
libxmlsec1
libxmlsec1-dev
swig
python-m2crypto
```

The second buildpack is the "[Heroku buildpack for Python apps, powered by pip](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python)".

So far so good.

#### Deploying to Heroku: Problem

The problem is that, while `apt` packages look like being installed successfully, when `pip install` actually runs, it seems not to find the `apt` packages installed.

If `apt` packages are being installed correctly, why is Python not finding them in the subsequent `pip install`?

This is the full `git push heroku` log:

```
git push heroku
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 932 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt
=====> Detected Framework: Apt
-----> Updating apt caches
       Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
       Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
       Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
       Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
       Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]
       Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
       Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
       Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [62.0 kB]
       Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [62.0 kB]
       Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
       Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
       Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
       Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
       Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [153 kB]
       Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
       Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [356 kB]
       Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
       Fetched 635 kB in 2s (247 kB/s)
       Reading package lists...
-----> Fetching .debs for python-setuptools
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       The following extra packages will be installed:
         python-pkg-resources
       Suggested packages:
         python-distribute python-distribute-doc
       The following NEW packages will be installed:
         python-pkg-resources python-setuptools
       0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
       Need to get 292 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 1017 kB of additional disk space will be used.
       Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-pkg-resources all 3.3-1ubuntu1 [61.9 kB]
       Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-setuptools all 3.3-1ubuntu1 [230 kB]
       Fetched 292 kB in 0s (408 kB/s)
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libxmlsec1
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       The following NEW packages will be installed:
         libxmlsec1
       0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/115 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 436 kB of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libxmlsec1-dev
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       The following extra packages will be installed:
         libnspr4 libnspr4-dev libnss3 libnss3-dev libnss3-nssdb libxmlsec1
         libxmlsec1-gcrypt libxmlsec1-gnutls libxmlsec1-nss libxmlsec1-openssl
       The following NEW packages will be installed:
         libnspr4 libnspr4-dev libnss3 libnss3-dev libnss3-nssdb libxmlsec1
         libxmlsec1-dev libxmlsec1-gcrypt libxmlsec1-gnutls libxmlsec1-nss
         libxmlsec1-openssl
       0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/2579 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 14.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for swig
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       The following extra packages will be installed:
         swig2.0
       Suggested packages:
         swig-doc swig-examples swig2.0-examples swig2.0-doc
       The following NEW packages will be installed:
         swig swig2.0
       0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/881 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 4412 kB of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for python-m2crypto
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       The following NEW packages will be installed:
         python-m2crypto
       0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/156 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 831 kB of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Installing libnspr4-dev_2%3a4.10.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libnspr4_2%3a4.10.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libnss3-dev_2%3a3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libnss3-nssdb_2%3a3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
-----> Installing libnss3_2%3a3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxmlsec1-dev_1.2.18-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxmlsec1-gcrypt_1.2.18-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxmlsec1-gnutls_1.2.18-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxmlsec1-nss_1.2.18-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxmlsec1-openssl_1.2.18-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxmlsec1_1.2.18-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing python-m2crypto_0.21.1-3ubuntu5_amd64.deb
-----> Installing python-pkg-resources_3.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb
-----> Installing python-setuptools_3.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb
-----> Installing swig2.0_2.0.11-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
-----> Installing swig_2.0.11-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
-----> Writing profile script
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
=====> Detected Framework: Python
-----> Installing dependencies with pip
       Downloading/unpacking dm.xmlsec.binding==1.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u45022/dm.xmlsec.binding/setup.py) egg_info for package dm.xmlsec.binding
           Error: cannot get XMLSec1 pre-processor and compiler flags; do you have the `libxmlsec1` development package installed?
           Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
           Error: cannot get XMLSec1 pre-processor and compiler flags; do you have the `libxmlsec1` development package installed?

       ----------------------------------------
       Cleaning up...
       Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_u45022/dm.xmlsec.binding
       Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app

To git@heroku.com:xxxxxxxxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.xxxxxxxxxxx.git'
```

Comment: Did you ever have any luck solving this Josvic?

Comment: @jb Nope. I did not have the chance to try the solution proposed in the answer below either as I had left the project that had the problem described in my question.

Comment: I'm working on this problem right now as well, and it seems that the problem is the apt buildpack installs packages in `/app/.apt` via dpkg, but in so doing, there's no configuration telling the packages that they're in `/app/.apt` rather than in `/` . Packages that use libxmlsec1 use `xmlsec1-config --cflags` , which, in this context prints out `/usr/include` rather than `/app/.apt/usr/include`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but maybe the answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441824/973380):

> With the amazing help of @PadraicCunningham I managed to find the solution. The problem turned out to be that heroku-buildpack-apt installs things in a newly created folder /app/.apt/ which was not in the `PYTHONPATH`.
>
> So I added the relevant folder to my PYTHONPATH on heroku as follows:
>
> `heroku config:add PYTHONPATH=/app/.apt/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

Comment: It won't help. `PYTHONPATH` tells python were to look for the packages, but pip seems to be unaware of this.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I was able to get xmlsec1 working on Heroku by doing the following two things:

1. Using a buildpack to install xmlsec1.
2. Using a [.profile.d script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/profiled) to configure `$PATH` to point at the xmlsec1 binary.

**Installing xmlsec1 using a buildpack**

I used [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi) with the [strydercorp/heroku-buildpack-xmlsec](https://github.com/strydercorp/heroku-buildpack-xmlsec) buildpack to install xmlsec1 into my Heroku instance. Note that this buildpack is for Cedar14, if you are on standard Cedar, you will want to use [evenco/heroku-buildpack-xmlsec](https://github.com/evenco/heroku-buildpack-xmlsec)

Here is what my `.buildpack` file looks like:

```
$ cat .buildpacks 
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
https://github.com/strydercorp/heroku-buildpack-xmlsec
```

**Configuring $PATH with a .profile.d script**

Once the xmlsec1 binary was installed on my Heroku instance, I needed to configure the `$PATH` variable to point at the xmlsec1 binary. Here is the `.profile.d` script I used to do that:

```
$ cat .profile.d/path.sh 
# https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/profiled

# add xmlsec1 binary and libraries to the appropriate paths
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/app/.heroku/xmlsec1-1.2/lib/"
PATH="$PATH:/app/.heroku/xmlsec1-1.2/bin/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is an OS dependency for any package in python, I prefer building Docker images on Heroku for hosting applications.

Create a Docker file in your root directory. A Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install libxmlsec1
RUN pip install requirements.txt
CMD python main.py
```

Write all the `apt` commands you want in the docker file and save it with name, `Dockerfile` . Do not give any extension to the file name.

Create a file named, heroku.yml. Paste the below lines of code to it:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

Use these commands to push your application to Heroku:

**1.** git add heroku.yml

**2** git commit -m "Add heroku.yml"

**3** heroku stack:set container

**4** git push heroku master